# How do I include something from another website?

Tags: php

I'm making a website for a charity song my school made and we have a just giving page where we've made about £600 already. What I want to do is have a running total on my site from the just giving page without having to constantly update it several times a day.

Is there anyway I can search that page for the item I want and include it on a page on my site? Like getElementById on javascript or something?

Comment: If any of the answers satisfied your question make sure you mark it as the one that answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on what page you're trying to extract data from.

First, you should check if Just Giving has an API which you can use to query the donations for a project. **EDIT:** After review, there is an [API](https://apimanagement.justgiving.com/) - this should be the preferred method!

Otherwise, you could try to see if the amount is stored in a specific div, which would make it easier to find the string. This find will have to be "string based" as your JavaScript won't be executed on the DOM of the fetched document. Therefore, you will need to use the `.search` function on a string and work from there until you find the value you want.

Very simple solutions would be to simply locate "£" in the document and take the string that follows until a space and display that as the amount of donations.

Comment: Thats sounds exactly like what I was thinking, I pressume this is with javascript? I'm not too familiar with javascript so have you got any pointers?

Comment: It can be done with any technology able to fetch the content of the other site, javascript should indeed work!

Comment: Just had a look, the running total has the class "raised-so-far", how do i locate that?

Comment: the just giving page isn't my own so I can't use the api

Comment: No, that's why they provide an API - see https://api.justgiving.com/docs and https://github.com/JustGiving/JustGiving.Api.Sdk/wiki for some examples

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the Just Giving site exposes a simple page with the snippet you want to show, you could simply get the page through AJAX using JQuery (with Javascript), and whatever you get you put it in your  or HTML element where you want to show it.

You can also have a Javascript timer which updates every few seconds if you have frequent donations (like every few seconds).

If you look at the [JQuery ajax() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there are some examples how to query another page and get its contents. Once you get the contents, you can use another [JQuery method called .html(htmlstring)](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which just replaces the HTML contents of your HTML element.

Say you have the contents of the page you just got through the `ajax()` method in variable `justgiving` , and you have a `<div id='justgiving-snippet'>` you can then just call `$('div#justgiving-snippet').html(justgiving);`

You have to get familiar a bit with Javascript but its quite easy. Check those 2 links above for more examples.

By the way, the `justgiving` variable you receive through AJAX can also be processed. So if you only want a snippet of it (say the contents of an element with class `raised-so-far`, you can do something like:

```
mysnippet = $('.raised-so-far', $(justgiving)).html();
```

Comment: I thought it would be javascript, i must say im not too familiar with it so any suggestions on what exactly I should do? Sorry to be a newbie.

Comment: I have included some more information for you, there are plenty of examples on the JQuery page which you can nearly copy and paste, and just adapt them for your own needs.

Comment: thanks, i had actually just found that first link you gave me whilst doing some googling

Comment: I updated my answer to include parsing the returned AJAX information to just extract the contents of the element with the class '.raised-so-far'

Answer (score -1):

This also works for adding "parts" or "modules" from one area of your site into another:

take the logic that pulls the Just Giving information and save it to a separate file. -Only- the just Giving logic, no styling, no html header / body / etc. Just the logic and the raw data you want printed on your other pages.

On your home or index page do  Place this where you want the data to display.

This will print the contents of the logic from the page "snippet". Think of this like a 'module' system. It's rude, its crude, but it should do what you need.

Comment: This approach works, however architecturally it is very messy. You are duplicating code, which means if you change it in one place you need to change it in the other. It also creates a deployment dependency, if they move database server, they would need to change two places. You are also assuming that he has full access to the business logic on the other side and that it is simple enough to port into the other system (no libraries, dependencies etc.)

Comment: O yea, very messy. Thus the "...It's rude, its crude, but it should do what you need..."

The only duplication would be the include_once on each page the OP wanted the data displayed. From the OP it sounded like a small project that, if true, may not even have abstraction of DB logic from business logic. But I digress.

Comment: Yes, but you're assuming that it is running on the same server (thus the include_once). From his comments it seems that he doesn't even have good access to the code itself, and he just wants to 'scrape' the information off from another site. You're right rude and crude would work, but why should we suggest the wrong thing, the whole point of this is for others having the same difficulty in the future to find previous answers no?

Comment: Touche sir, touche. Point well made.